# How to get complete history of a file, including deletes, renames and the source of copy/rename?

Tags: mercurial

The --removed and --follow switches seem to be incompatible so I can get either deletions or copy / renames.

I also want to find the source of the rename or copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `--removed` doesn't work with `--follow` seems like a bug.  You get file copies using:

```
hg --verbose -C -f <file>
```

or use a custom template using `{file_copies}`:

```
hg log --template "changeset: {node|short}\nuser: {author}\ndate: {date|rfc822date}\nfile+: {file_adds}\nfilem: {file_mods}\nfile-: {file_dels}\nfilec: {file_copies}\nsummary: {desc|firstline}\n\n" -f file2
```

Comment: The output shows all files - filec: file1.txt (file1)file2.txt (file2)file4.txt (file4) -- the format of file (source) is not very robust (e.g. in Windows, parentheses are valid filename characters).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom template to display and also to format the file-copy messages properly:

```
hg log --template "{rev}\n{file_copies % '  {file_copy}\n'}\n" --follow <file_name>
```

More about custom templates:

```
hg help -v templates
```